# How is this code showing this output?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    cout << s.length() << " ";
    int l = s.length();
    int i = l;
    while (s[i] >= 0)
    {
        i--;
    }
    cout << i;
    return 0;
}
```

When I give input `10101`, output is:

```
5 -12
```

How is index going so low?

Comment: What are expecting to happen when `i` reaches 0?

Comment: You will be going out of bounds of the string, reading indeterminate memory values, and have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: because the test verifies the integer value of the character at position 'i' of s is negative. You're going back out of bound until in the stack you find a negative integer.

Comment: As for help with possible solutions, please tell us what the code is supposed to do? For the input you show, what should the *expected* output be?

Comment: On a side note, in the code above, when I change i=length-1; condition in while to while(s[i]==1) {i--;} for same input 10101 I'm getting 5 4. But I'm expecting 5 3

Comment: Perhaps you mean the condition to be `s[i] == '1'` since you're comparing ***characters***? Note the use of single-quotes around the digit. Also note that since you initialize `i` to `s.length()` you're indexing `s[s.length()]` which is *also* out of bounds. You should initialize `i` to `s.length() - 1`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh yes, it works now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As "i" is decremented it will go outside of the bounds of the string. It then accesses indeterminate memory values. Some of these happen to be greater or equal to 0.